# Android: How to extract the words with Bold Span formatt from an Edit Text and add them to a list.

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have set a Bold Span to some specific words in an EditText, now i want to get these words from EditText and add them into a list.
How can i be able to find what words are bold and add them to the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this.

```
EditText t /* assign EditText instance */
Editable text = t.getText();
StyleSpan[] spans = text.getSpans(0 , text.length(), StyleSpan.class); 
ArrayList<CharSequence> list = new ArrayList<CharSequence>(10); 
for (StyleSpan s : spans){
    if (s.getStyle() == android.graphics.Typeface.BOLD){
        int start = text.getSpanStart(s);
        int end = text.getSpanEnd(s);
        CharSequence cs = text.subSequence(start, end+1); 
        list.add(cs); 
    }
}
```